# PARTITION BY Name, Id to compare and detect problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

**EXPLAINATION**

Imagine that here are 3 companies. We are joining tables by `Name`, that because not every employee have provided his `PersonalNo`. `StringId` have only specialists, so It can't be used for joining too. The same employee can work in multiple companies.

---

**PROBLEM**

Problem is that there can be different employees with the same name (with equal first and last names, in example provided only first name).

---

**WHAT I NEED?**

Return `1` when there are any problems with data and `0` If It is correct.

---

**RULES TO DETECT PROBLEM**

1. When have multiple equal names (*2 or more*) and all have equal `PersonalNo` and not all have `StringId` (*as Peter*) should return `1` (*It is wrong*)
2. When have multiple equal names (*2 or more*) and there are `NULL` (*see John*), but all of them have the same `StringId` It should return `0` (*It's correct, that means one of companies not provided `PersonalNo`*)
3. When have multiple equal names (*2 or more*) and all `PersonalNo` are equal and all `StringId` are equall (*see at Lisa*) It should return `0` (*correct*)
4. When have multiple equal names (*2 or more*) and there are multiple different `PersonalNo` and all `StringId` provided It should be like: We see that here are 2 different people Jennifer with `4805250141` `PersonalNo` and Jennifer with `4920225088` `PersonalNo`, Jennifer with `NULL` `PersonalNo` have the same `StringId` as Jennifer with `4920225088` `PersonalNo` so It should return `0` (*correct*) and Jennifer with `4805250141` `PersonalNo` shouldn't be selected, because have `StringID` and have only 1 row with the same `PersonalNo`.
5. If there is only 1 row and there is no provided `StringId` It shouldn't appear in select at all.

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Company     Name        PersonalNo   StringId 
Comp1       Peter       3850342515    85426 -------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp2       Peter       3850342515    ''    -- If have the same PersonalNo and there is no StringId - 1 (wrong)
Comp1       John        NULL          12345 ------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp2       John        3952525252    12345 -- If have the same StringId and 1 PersonalNo is NULL - 0 (correct)
Comp1       Lisa        4951212581    52124 ----------------------------------------------------------------
Comp3       Lisa        4951212581    52124 -- If PersonalNo are equal and StringId are equal - 0 (correct)
Comp1       Jennifer    4805250141    ''    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comp1       Jennifer    4920225088    55443 -- If have 2 different PersonalNo and NULL PersonalNo, but where PersonalNo is NULL 
Comp3       Jennifer    NULL          55443 -- Have the same StringId with other row where is provided PersonalNo it should be 0 (correct), with different PersonalNo where is no StringId shouldn't appear at all.
Comp1       Ralph       3961212256    ''    -- Shouldn't appear in select list, because only 1 row with this PersonalNo and there is no StringID
```

---

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Peter     1
John      0
Lisa      0
Jennifer  0
```

---

**QUERY**

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name,                 
                    (
                    SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(PersonalNo) <> MAX(d.PersonalNo) 
                                    and MIN(CASE WHEN StringId IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE StringId END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN d.StringId IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE d.StringId END) -- this is wrong                                                 
                                    and MIN(PersonalNo) <> ''
                                    and MIN(PersonalNo) IS NOT NULL                          
                                    and MAX(rn) > 1 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END AS CheckPersonalNo 
                    FROM (                               
                        SELECT Name, PersonalNo, [StringId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, PersonalNo ORDER BY Name) rn
                        FROM TableEmp e1 
                        WHERE Condition = 1 and e1.Name = d.Name                                 
                        ) sub2                              
                    GROUP BY Name
                    ) CheckPersonalNo                                                                                   
        FROM [TableEmp] d   
        WHERE Condition = 1
        GROUP BY Name        
        ) f ON f.Name = x.Name
```

Problem with query is that I can group by `Name` only, can't add `PersonalNo` to `GROUP BY` clause, so I need to use aggregates in select list. But for now It comparing only `MIN` and `MAX` values, If there is more than 2 rows with the same name It not working as expected.

I need to do something like, compare values by `PARTITION BY Fullname, PersonalNo`. It for now comparing values with the same `Name` (not depending to `PersonalNo`).

Any ideas? If you have any questions - ask me, I will try to explain.

---

**UPDATE 1**

If there is 2 entries with different `PersonalNo`, but their `StringId` are equal, It should be `1` (wrong).

```
Company     Name    PersonalNo   StringId 
Comp1       Anna    4805250141    88552    -- different PersonalNo and the same StringId for both should go as 1 (wrong)
Comp1       Anna    4920225088    88552
```

For now It returning like:

```
Anna    0
Anna    0
```

It should be:

```
Anna    1
```

**UPDATE 2**

After you `UNION` update in `Identifier` column returns `StringId: 55443` (for data below), but in this case when 1 entry have `PersonalNo`, other is `blank`, but both of them have the same (equal) `StringId` It is correct (should be 0)

```
Comp1       Jennifer    4920225088    55443  
Comp3       Jennifer    ''            55443
```

Comment: Are there only 3 companies? And are the names fixed?

Comment: No, there are hundreds of companies and millions of employees. There can be more conditions when It is wrong, but I will make It by myself, I only need Idea, how to make comparing by partition by Name, PersonalNo, to compare values depending on PersonalNo too.

Comment: Can PersonalNo be different(not null) but  stringid same and vice-versa?

Comment: @Sameer Yes, It can be, so in this case It should return 1 (wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope i have understood your requirements..

There maybe other ways of doing this but personally i would probably use temp tables for interim working if it was me doing it..

```
--select data into a temp table that can be modified
select
    *
    into #cleaned
from 
    table


--apply personal numbers based on other records with matching string id
--you could take note of the records you are doing this to for data clean up
update c
    set c.personalNo = s.personalNo
from #cleaned as c
    inner join table as s
        on c.name = s.name
        and c.stringID = s.stringID
        and c.personalNo is null
        and s.personalNo is not null

--find all records with non matching string ids
select 
    name
    ,PersonalNo
    ,count(*) as numIDs
    into #issues
from(
    select
        name
        ,PersonalNo
        ,stringID
    from 
        #cleaned
    group by
        name
        ,PersonalNo
        ,stringID
    ) as i
group by
    name
    ,PersonalNo
having 
    count(*) > 1

--select data for viewing.
select
    distinct
    s.name
    ,case
        when i.name is not null then 1
        else 0
    end as issue
from
    #cleaned as s
    left outer join #issues as i
        on s.name = i.name
        and s.personalNo = i.personalNo
order by issue desc
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4aab/7

sorry if there are bugs in here but i am sure you will get the idea, its not rocket science, just another approach

**EDIT**: just noticed you are interested in rows with no string ID.. just if its the only row then it is not an issue. i modified first select (into #cleaned) to take all rows.

**EDIT**: **NO Temp Tables** now you know what its doing, here is the same thing without any temp tables - but **WARNING** this updates the source tables to assign missing personalNo's

```
update c
    set c.personalNo = s.personalNo
from table1 as c
    inner join table1 as s
        on c.name = s.name
        and c.stringID = s.stringID
        and c.personalNo is null
        and s.personalNo is not null


select
    distinct
    s.name
    ,case
        when i.name is not null then 1
        else 0
    end as issue
from
    table1 as s
    left outer join (
                select 
                    name
                    ,PersonalNo
                    ,count(*) as numIDs
                from(
                    select
                        name
                        ,PersonalNo
                        ,stringID
                    from 
                        table1
                    group by
                        name
                        ,PersonalNo
                        ,stringID
                    ) as i
                group by
                    name
                    ,PersonalNo
                having 
                    count(*) > 1
        )
        as i
        on s.name = i.name
        and s.personalNo = i.personalNo
order by issue desc
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4aab/8

**PARITIONING** i dont see how i would use partitioning here as what you want to do is only know if there is more than one row, i use partitioning from more complex tabulation or if i was going to rank the results of make judgement calls on updating data based on more complex rules.. but in any case here is a crow barred in partition by  :D

```
Select
    name
    ,personalNo
    ,case
        when numstrings > 1 then 1
        else 0 end as issue
from
    (select
        name
        ,personalNo
        ,row_number() over (partition by 
                                    name
                                    ,personalNo 
                                order by 
                                    name
                                    ,personalNo
                                    ,stringID
                                    ) as numstrings
    from
        #cleaned
    group by
        name
        ,personalNo
        ,stringid) as d
order by
    issue desc
```

NOTE: this uses the #cleaned table as above, as i believe that the crux of what makes this hard is the sometimes missing personalNo's.

**No temp tables, no updates**

Working with above its obviously possible to do without any temp tables or updating anything, its just a question of readability / maintainability and also whether or not it is actually even any faster. this could be made more stable to handle string ids with multiple personalNo's assigned:

```
select
    distinct
    s.name
    ,case
        when i.name is not null then 1
        else 0
    end as issue
from
    table1 as s
    left outer join (
                select 
                    name
                    ,PersonalNo
                    ,count(*) as numIDs
                from(
                    select
                        a.name
                        ,coalesce(a.PersonalNo,b.PersonalNo) as PersonalNo
                        ,a.stringID
                    from 
                        table1 as a
                            left outer join table1 as b
                                on a.name = b.name
                                and a.stringid=b.stringid
                                and a.personalNo != b.personalNo
                                and b.personalNo Is Not Null
                    group by
                        a.name
                        ,a.PersonalNo
                        ,a.stringID
                        ,b.PersonalNo
                    ) as i
                group by
                    name
                    ,PersonalNo
                having 
                    count(*) > 1
        )
        as i
        on s.name = i.name
        and s.personalNo = i.personalNo
order by issue desc
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4aab/9

**EDIT: Looking for inconsistent personal numbers too** - this uses one temp table, but you could swap it out as done in last example.. NOTE there is a slight deviation from the original structure you asked for as this is more how i would do this task, but there is more than enough code here for you to re-jig any way you want.

```
--select data into a temp table that can be modified
select
    *
    into #cleaned
from 
    table1


--apply personal numbers based on other records with matching string id
--you could take note of the records you are doing this to for data clean up
update c
    set c.personalNo = s.personalNo
from #cleaned as c
    inner join table1 as s
        on c.name = s.name
        and c.stringID = s.stringID
        and c.personalNo is null
        and s.personalNo is not null


Select
    IssueType
     ,Name
     ,Identifier
from 
    (
        --find all records with non matching PersonalNos
        select 
            name
            ,cast('StringID: ' + stringID as nvarchar(400)) as Identifier
            ,cast('Inconsistent  PersonalNo' as nvarchar(400)) as issueType
        from(
            select
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            from 
                #cleaned
            group by
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            ) as i
        group by
            name
            ,StringId
        having 
            count(*) > 1

    UNION    
        --find all records with non matching string ids

        select 
            name
            ,'PersonalNo: ' + PersonalNo
            ,cast('Inconsistent String ID' as nvarchar(400)) as issueType
        from(
            select
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            from 
                #cleaned
            group by
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            ) as i
        group by
            name
            ,PersonalNo
        having 
            count(*) > 1
    ) as a
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9da2/18

**UPDATE: also wanting to accept empty string personalNo's**
This is another new requirement.. to accept empty strings in teh same way as NULLs in personalNo

```
--select data into a temp table that can be modified
select
    *
    into #cleaned
from 
    table1

--apply personal numbers based on other records with matching string id
--you could take note of the records you are doing this to for data clean up
update c
    set c.personalNo = s.personalNo
from #cleaned as c
    inner join table1 as s
        on c.name = s.name
        and c.stringID = s.stringID
        and  (c.personalNo IS NULL OR c.personalNo ='')
        and s.personalNo is not null
        and s.personalNo != ''


Select
     IssueType
     ,Name
     ,Identifier
from 
    (
        --find all records with non matching PersonalNos
        select 
            name
            ,cast('StringID: ' + stringID as nvarchar(400)) as Identifier
            ,cast('Inconsistent  PersonalNo' as nvarchar(400)) as issueType
        from(
            select
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            from 
                #cleaned
            group by
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            ) as i
        group by
            name
            ,StringId
        having 
            count(*) > 1

  UNION    
        --find all records with non matching string ids
        select 
            name
            ,'PersonalNo: ' + PersonalNo
            ,cast('Inconsistent String ID' as nvarchar(400)) as issueType
        from(
            select
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            from 
                #cleaned
            group by
                name
                ,PersonalNo
                ,stringID
            ) as i
        group by
            name
            ,PersonalNo
        having 
            count(*) > 1
    ) as a
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412127/8

Comment: Thank you for answer, I hope that here is another way to achieve It. Even If this worked seems It took so long to execute this query. In my question provided query is using as sub-query for join tables. There are millions of records, to insert all of them to #temp table, later join table with #temp It will take extremely long, am I wrong?

Comment: i would test it, ive certainly used this type of thing for millions of rows before without issue still executed in seconds or less.. but a few questions: 1. is this a data clean up task? if so execution time should not be an issue, 2. what makes you think a complex partitioning will be fast? 3. can you think of any other way to make it actually work without fixing your conflicting personalNo's first? .. i will add a "partition by solution" to the answer but its of no use here IMHO - the real source of the problem is aligning those personalNo's first

Comment: This is used for Reporting Services, to see If data is correct for all emplyees. I will test It and will tell you If It worked for me.

Comment: added some additional info - and a non temp table version, maybe some ninja has a better way of doing it but at least you will have something that works :)

Comment: if it was me i would hope to get business approval to assign missing personalNo's based on stringIDs. that way you can go straight to the answer and you don't need the temp table in the middle. or make two reports on on missing personalNo's and one for misaligned data that also show missing personalNo's as a by product as it may be simpler for business to understand.

Comment: This not working when employee with same (equal) name (for example: Lisa) have 2 different PersonalNo and equal StringId. It should be 1 (wrong), look at my updated question. Have you ideas, how to solve It?

Comment: Updated the answer, these types of extra requirements are why i lean towards temp tables in these types of problems but i have given a solution using a union which is also a fairly clean way to do it

Comment: Here is also problem, look at updated question (Update 2) and with `Insert into #issues` row something wrong (incorrect syntax) so I removed It at all.

Comment: Yes that was a typo sorry i have corrected it see SQLFiddle for running example though.. as for your second update i don't know what you mean, there is a user 'john' in the SQLFiddle that seems to do exactly what you are saying and works fine

Comment: Look at my SQL Fiddle sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412127/1 `Rocky`. `John` have `NULL` in `PersonalNo` so It working fine, but there can be blank ('') `PersonalNo` too.

Comment: This is because its not null its an empty string, you just have to code for that too. I have updated the answer but please mark this question answered and ask a new question is you are having subsequent issues like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

Comment: You are very welcome, i hope it helps. you have a working SQL fiddle that pretty clearly specifies everything. questions here are meant to be specific rather than ongoing support with a task.